# Why cannot I inflate and add a ViewGroup as a child view in constructor of another ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a class extended from `RelativeLayout` named `LabelMenuButton`. Inside its constructor, I am doing:

```
public LabelMenuButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LabelMenuButton, 0, 0);
    String headingText;
    String valueText;

    try {
        headingText = a.getString(R.styleable.LabelMenuButton_headingText);
        valueText = a.getString(R.styleable.LabelMenuButton_valueText);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

    addView(inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_label_menu_button, this));

    tvHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_lbl_menu_btn_heading);
    tvValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_lbl_menu_btn_value);

    setHeadingText(headingText);
    setValueText(valueText);
}
```

I am using the `LabelMenuButton` class in XML layout of an activity:

```
<com.blah.blah.blah.LabelMenuButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    app:headingText="Sample heading"
    app:valueText="Sample value" />
```

But I get following exception when, I believe, that activity's content is being set:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blah.blah.blah/com.blah.blah.blah.MyActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #105: Error inflating class com.blah.blah.blah.LabelMenuButton
```

view_label_menu_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lbl_menu_btn_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Heading" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lbl_menu_btn_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Value" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you put whole Constructor code and tell us how you use this custom view (in java or in a xml layout file) ?

Comment: I think @laalto has the right answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> addView(inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_label_menu_button, this));
> ```

`inflate()` already attaches the inflated view to the supplied parent root (`this` here) unless you use the [3-arg version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) with `attachToRoot` set to `false`. Adding the view again to a parent causes the "already has a parent" exception.

You can remove the `addView()` here.

Comment: Oh... I should be killing myself. This was driving me crazy and such a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing out.